# Preventing Google Analytics from counting traffic to a custom URL

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I connected my website to Analytics 4 via GTM. However, I have a request: I want GA4 not to count the traffic coming to a link I specify within my site. Is something like this possible?

For example, let's say I set website.com/link_url. It won't count traffic to it.

But it will continue to calculate all traffic to the website.com domain normally, except for the URL address I chose.

Thank you...

I tried on GTM but it didn't work

Comment: Probably as simple as not putting your Analytics JavaScript snippet on that page.  Or is there some reason that wouldn't work?

Comment: I put my Analytics snippet everywhere except one page. but it counted all traffic, including those arriving at the selected link. Actually I want this: Is there a way to not count only a selected page in GTM or Analytics? Sorry my bad English...

Comment: There is no way to count the traffic to the page if it doesn't have your analytics snippet on it.